# Jquery is not firing to fetch mysql database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fetch the phpmyadmin values to the second select field by selecting the first select field. I am not sure where its gone wrong.  Its not firing the first select value to my php file.

```
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        </head>

<body>
        <select id="first-choice">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1001">Hotel 1</option>
            <option value="1003">Hotel 2</option>
            <option value="1004">Hotel 3</option>
            <option value="1005">Hotel 4</option>
        </select>

        <br />

        <select id="second-choice">
            <option>Please choose from above</option>
        </select>

<script language="javascript">
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
$("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
}).trigger("change");
</script>

</body>
```

gitter.php code

```
$choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE hotel_id = '$choice'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['room_id'].'">' . $row['full_name'] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Show your `getter.php` code

Comment: @Apb, i added the getter code.. but the script is not going to getter page. I tried adding echo 'hello'; exit; at the top of the page. . but its not showing.. The script is not firing.

Comment: To debug your code, use the console (for Chrome on Windows: Ctrl + Shift + J), apart from that, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document isn't "ready" to execute the JS. Use for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Your code
});
```

See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Also, to see the errors produced by your Javascript, open the console. (Ctrl + Shift + J in Chrome)

Comment: What does console tell you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery not ready yet. You can try This way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
$("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
}).trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Another Mistake in your php file name Spelling  **gitter.php**

Answer (score 0):

You can have some errors

First add a `$(document).ready(function() {});`

After that make sure that your url is right. Here `getter.php` is in the same folder than your html page.

Change your php query to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE hotel_id = '".$choice."'";
```